# Cannot get length in array

Tags: javascript

I could not even get the alert prompt. What wrong did I done on IE9?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var countrieslist=document.sc.s1
    var subjlist=document.sc.s2

    var subj=new Array()
    subj[0]=""
    subj[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue", "Los Angeles|loangelesvalue", "Chicago|chicagovalue", "Houston|houstonvalue", "Austin|austinvalue"]
    subj[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue", "Tonronto|torontovalue", "Montreal|montrealvalue", "Calgary|calgaryvalue"]
    subj[3]=["London|londonvalue", "Glasgow|glasgowsvalue", "Manchester|manchestervalue", "Edinburgh|edinburghvalue", "Birmingham|birminghamvalue"]

function updateSubj(selectsubj) {
    if (selectsubj>0){
        for (i=0; i<subj[selectsubj].length; i++) {
        alert("ss");
            //s2.options[subjlist.options.length]=new Option(subj[selectsubj][i].split("|")[0], subj[selectsubj][i].split("|")[1])
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: that means the subj[selectsubj] doesn't have any items. try alerting the length before the for loop

Comment: I tried change to subj[1].length but it still doesn't alert.

Comment: Where are you calling updateSubj?, which is the selectsubj value?, are you sure its > 0, right?

Comment: I can set updateSubj(1), on outside the for loop, the alert is working but when the alert is inside the for loop, it won't appear. IE9 has bug?

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide an exact example of what you are doing at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Huh? but you can try the code to see if it for for your case? My colleague is unable to get it work too.

Comment: put it in jsfiddle and show us the bug please :)

Answer (score 0):

I should check if it is an array.

```
function update (i) {
    if (subj[i] instanceof Array)
        for(var j in subj[i])
            alert(subj[i][j]);
    else
        alert(subj[i] || 'is undefined');
}
```

You can also check if it's an iterable by checking the length property

```
if (subj[i].length) // iterate list
```